# EC2 instance: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, multithreading, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, moviepy

I am have a EC2 instance, which host an Elastic Beanstalk environment  (Linux and Python) with configuration:

- Instance type: c5.2xlarge
- Root volume size: 1000 GiB

In my python file, I create 60 threads to process crop video (using [moviepy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy)), each thread will crop 10 videos (total 10MB). When I run the file, it returned the error "Cannot allocate memory". I know it's about out of memory, but I don't know how to measure and setup the capacity of EC2 instance to avoid of this issue.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried fewer thread to verify it's not a capacity issue?

Comment: yes, I tried with 5-6 threads, it worked properly. My point is, if I want to run 60 threads (may be more) like this, how can I configure EC2 instance to adopt that heavy workload without out of memory

Comment: Why not make a rule to add more EC2 instance depending on memory utilization. E.g. you may setup a rule to spin an EC2 instance as soon as memory utilization reaches to 80%.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the capacity, I recommend setting up an [Auto-Scaling group in Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html). You will need to experiment with the size of your instances as you probably will not want to spin up an extra c5.2xlarge volume just to execute a handful of extra threads.